# Timer Job depoys and activates through VS2010, but not through site settings

Tags: 2010

I have created a timer job that works correctly when deploying by right clicking the project and hitting deploy in Visual Studio.

However, if I deploy the solution to the same server with a WSP file, I get an error when activating the feature at the site collection level. Similarly, if I deploy through VS2010 directly to the site, I get an error when deactivating the feature at the site collection level.

Does VS2010 do something different that allows the solution to be activated despite running into an error when done manually? Does this mean there is a bug in my event receiver feature for the timer job?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How are you activating the feature? Timer jobs can't be activated through the GUI (i.e., Site Settings -> Site Collection Features) -- you'll need to use PowerShell (SP-EnableFeature).

Comment: Ohh... is that why? I see the feature listed in the site collection settings, but I actually am not allowed to click "Activate" here and have to enable it through powershell? Is that what you mean?

Comment: Okay, apparently the pretty little activate button in the GUI is just for show in this case. I went ahead and activated through powershell and it worked. Thanks, Ted.

Comment: Cool, glad that worked! I had this error before - I guess it comes down to database permissions... the server account that would execute the command through the GUI doesn't have the right permissions.